# Python question: My function isn't running, using the input values I have set. Python 3.9

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function to convert DMS to DD.  My function isn't running utilizing the import answer I provide.  I an new to python, any assistance would be great.

```
import math

def d_m_s(d,m,s):
    d = int(d)
    m = int(m)
    s = int(s)
    dd = d + m/60 + s/3600
    print(dd)


d,m,s = input("Enter degrees, minutes, and seconds:").split(',')
print(type(d))
```

Comment: you didn't call the function

Comment: You need to call your method `d_m_s`. Try adding this after your `input` line: `d_m_s(d, m, s)` and see what happens.

Comment: replace `print(type(d))` which will give you the data type of d with `d_m_s(d,m,s)` to get the result printed.

Answer (score 1):

You have called the `type()` function in your print statement.  This will just tell you if d is a string, int, float, etc.  In order to print "d", just use `print(d)`.

However, in order to print the DD conversion, instead of ending with a print statement, you can replace the last line with `d_m_s(d,m,s)`

Hope this helps!